# Bootstrap input-append and backface-visibility

Tags: google-chrome, css, twitter-bootstrap, webkit

I'm having some problems using a Bootstrap input and the css backface-visiblity attribute (only in Chrome).

I'd like to have two views; one of them only visible at the same time. An animation flips over the currently active view and shows the 'back face' view.
This works all fine, but for some reason when I add a Bootstrap input on one side, it doesn't get hidden when I flip over the view (see http://jsfiddle.net/AfnLc/). I went through bootstrap.less and identified the part that is responsible.

```
.input-append input,
.input-prepend input,
.input-append select,
.input-prepend select,
.input-append .uneditable-input,
.input-prepend .uneditable-input {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  *margin-left: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
          border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
```

If I remove the `position: relative` line, it all works fine, but I'm reluctant to do this as it's (1) changing Bootstrap and (2) might have side effects to the rest of the application.

Does anyone know about how to fix this properly or has a workaround? This problem only seems to occur for me in Chrome and Safari (both Mac OS X), but not in Firefox (Mac OS X).

Edit: iOS Chrome and Safari have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by just overriding the position attribute locally with `position:static`. This shouldn't cause any harm as I use this input in a table. http://jsfiddle.net/9CHEb/1/

Edit: changed posityion:static into position:static